# Obfuscating encryption password in source code and difficulty of hacking

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords, obfuscation

I am developing mobile game based on C# language. The game's save file will be encrypted by simple password that is stored in the source code. If player were to easily see and edit this file the game would be too easy.

The game itself is not online so if he managed to hack it, it will not bother or create unfairness to other people, so I didn't bother about security that much and I choose to store the password in the code directly to reduce my hassle also.

However I guess with some decompiler someone can directly see the password being declared? I want to ask about some simple way to make password-in-the-source harder to hack. For example, currently I read the password from  `public static readonly` variable. I wonder which one of these adds difficulty to the hacker, or not at all?

- Change to `private static readonly` variable.
- Change to `private` variable of the class. (I am guessing the heap where static variable is stored is easier to hack?)
- Change to local variable of save file reading method.
- Split the string to several parts and place it in different source files. At the point that code reads save file, it reassemble all the pieces by concatenating them all sequentially.
- I create a long seemingly random string that looks like a password, but actually I will pick only some characters from it to construct the true password.
- There are 2 passwords. The first one is being encrypted using another password as an encryption key. Decrypt the password to get the true password. Both password will be stored directly in the source code.

I guess I have to know how C# decompiler works, but I have no idea about it. If you have better idea that is not so hard to implement, feel free to add.

Comment: You could just encrypt it in the config. Security through obscurity is no security at all. Here is a tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: Security through obscurity does not work and if someone is interested in your code, he will get it. Like always: "The computer can read it => it was built by human beings => they can read it".
Passwords do not belong into the code, even if there is no big lack of security caused by it.

Comment: Changing the variable location, visibility, scope, etc. doesn't make things harder. Decompilers just decompile the code into plain text, pretty much like you wrote it in Visual Studio (or what IDE you are using). So for example, `private string password = "Hello";` will be decompiled to `private string password = "Hello";`

Comment: Oh, I never thought C# also remembered variable names exactly as typed even after compilation. So the best way is to make it hard to read by human, like post processing the important source file, replacing variable names with hard to read characters or make a single long function I guess?